# Show post number in relation to category

Tags: php, wordpress

I asked this question yesterday a bit confusing so I will try a better one today:

I use the following script to count post per post:

functions.php

```
function Get_Post_Number($postID){
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1');
    $counter = 1;
    $postCount = 0;
    if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
        while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
            if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
                $postCount = $counter;
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    return $postCount;
}
```

single.php

```
<?php $currentID = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php $currentNumber = Get_Post_Number($currentID); ?>
<?php echo $currentNumber; ?>
```

The result:

category 1 has 3 posts
post-page 1 (cat 1) show me -> **1** of 3
post-page 2 (cat 1) show me -> **2** of 3
post-page 3 (cat 1) show me -> **3** of 3

category 2 has 2 posts
post-page 1 (cat 2) show me -> **4** of 2
post-page 2 (cat 2) show me -> **5** of 2

**The bold number is from the script** and the problem is, that it counts from the first post till the last, without regard to the category.

The correct count should be:

category 1 has 3 posts
post-page 1 (cat 1) show me -> **1** of 3
post-page 2 (cat 1) show me -> **2** of 3
post-page 3 (cat 1) show me -> **3** of 3

category 2 has 2 posts
post-page 1 (cat 2) show me -> **1** of 2
post-page 2 (cat 2) show me -> **2** of 2

Anybody able to help me fixing this problem?

**Update**

Thats what I try at the moment, it always counts the max. of posts - for me its always "8". ;(:

functions.php

```
function Get_Post_Number($category){
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1&category=$category');
$counter = 1;
$postCount = 0;
if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
    while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
        $postCount++;
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
$wp_query = $temp_query;
return $postCount;
}
```

single.php

```
<?php $currentCat = get_the_Category(); ?> // Change to get the Category and not the id
<?php $currentNumber = Get_Post_Number($currentCat); ?>
<?php echo $currentNumber; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching by the category and just doing a count instead?

```
<?php $currentCat = get_the_Category(); ?> // Change to get the Category and not the id
<?php $currentNumber = Get_Post_Number($currentCat); ?>
<?php echo $currentNumber; ?>

function Get_Post_Number($category){
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1&category=$category');
    $counter = 1;
    $postCount = 0;
    if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
        while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
            if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
                $postCount = $counter;
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    return $postCount;
}
```

Comment: I try your updated script, but now I always get a "1" ;(.

Comment: Can you use the category in your query and then just, change postID to CategoryID and get_the_ID to get_the_category.
the problem is that you are trying to group the results by the category, but you are searching by the id

Comment: I try it at the functions.php, but now I get always "0".

Comment: Now I get always the max. count of all posts = "8".

Comment: did you create a function for 'get_the_Category()'?

Comment: Yes, like I added on the top of this post at "Update"

Comment: Can you show the function behind 'get_the_Category()'?

Comment: Sry, what you mean with this?

Comment: basically you have 'get_the_ID()' that is producing the current id.  and obviously 'get_the_Category()' is not returning anything, if you get the 'get_the_Category function to return results then everything will work.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think understand what you mean ... I thought I need the category to count posts per posts of every category? Otherwise wp will count post per post without regard to the category? So the category should only be a check for the script which posts are a part of it and then it counts (for every category and post) ... post 1 of 3 (cat 1), 2 of 3 (cat 1), 3 of 3 (cat1).

Comment: I do believe, we are now on the same wave length =]

Answer (score 0):

You always query for all items and as a result you get the larger number.

I think you need to include the category in your query so that you only get three results for category 1 and two results for category 2, then numbering will be ok.

Something similar to the below, depending on what your database schema looks like...

```
function Get_Post_Number($postID,$category){
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1&category_name=$category');
    $counter = 1;
    $postCount = 0;
    if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
        while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
            if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
                $postCount = $counter;
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    return $postCount;
}
```

And update single.php

```
<?php $currentID = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php $currentNumber = Get_Post_Number($currentID,$category); ?>
<?php echo $currentNumber; ?>
```

Update: Added code for single.php

Comment: also thx for your support - interesting way, but it also doesn´t work ;( - same count fail.

Comment: But if you limit the number of rows returned from WP_Query to 2 by making sure only category 2 rows are included, how can the count then still be 5?

Comment: @Pepe did you update the single.php to send the category through?
Also with this query, you wouldn't need the postId, and the loop could just be $postCount++;

Comment: Yes, I also updated the single.php like Mattias - but the count fails ;(. Do I need a loop for the post (if have post aso.)?

Comment: Could you post your code now? As it has changed since you started

Comment: In your code you are not actually getting the Category, you will need to get the category as currently '$category' is just an empty string.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't realize it was wordpress... But looking it up there seems to be parameters 'category_name'  and 'cat', the first is the string value and the second is the category id. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628. I updated the sample above assuming you have the category name and not the id. As krisph say you of course need to load $category with the proper value, but as you write "category 1" and "category 2" in your output I assume you have this available.

Comment: Ouh, ok ... maybe my fail, but I think I am not able to modify this script with your link/list ;(.

Comment: Ok, so category_name=$category was not the correct selection in the query? They I'm out of ideas, sorry...